# Postgres generate date series with exactly 100 steps

Tags: postgresql, series

Lets say we have the dates

```
'2017-01-01'
and
'2017-01-15'
```

and I would like to get a series of exactly N timestamps in between these dates, in this case 7 dates:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    generate_series_n(
        '2017-01-01'::timestamp,
        '2017-01-04'::timestamp,
        7
    )
```

Which I would like to return something like this:

```
2017-01-01-00:00:00
2017-01-01-12:00:00
2017-01-02-00:00:00
2017-01-02-12:00:00
2017-01-03-00:00:00
2017-01-03-12:00:00
2017-01-04-00:00:00
```

How can I do this in postgres?

Comment: What's wrong with `generate_series('2017-01-01'::timestamp,'2017-01-15'::timestamp, interval '1 day')`

Comment: this was just an example. I want one that can work with any number. I will change the post to make that clear

Comment: Isn't the number of values defined by the start and end values? What would you expect from `2017-01-01, 2017-07-01, 15` or `2017-01-01, 2017-01-02, 15`?

Comment: Sorry I should have said timestamps, not dates. In the case of 2017-01-01 2017-07-01 15 it would be timestamps that are exactly 12.063888889 days (or 289.533333333 hours) apart

Comment: Is `generate_series(tsA, tsB, (tsB-tsA) / N)` what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly this can be useful, using the generate series, and doing the math in the select

```
select '2022-01-01'::date + generate_series *('2022-05-31'::date - '2022-01-01'::date)/15 
FROM generate_series(1, 15)
;
```

output

```
  ?column?
------------
 2022-01-11
 2022-01-21
 2022-01-31
 2022-02-10
 2022-02-20
 2022-03-02
 2022-03-12
 2022-03-22
 2022-04-01
 2022-04-11
 2022-04-21
 2022-05-01
 2022-05-11
 2022-05-21
 2022-05-31
(15 rows)
```

Comment: generate_series *('2022-05-31'::date - '2022-01-01'::date) what does the star mean?

Comment: it's the multiplying operator

Comment: oh its treated as a column i get it now

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH seconds AS 
(
    SELECT EXTRACT(epoch FROM('2017-01-04'::timestamp - '2017-01-01'::timestamp))::integer AS sec
), 
 step_seconds AS
(
    SELECT sec / 7 AS step FROM seconds
)
SELECT generate_series('2017-01-01'::timestamp, '2017-01-04'::timestamp, (step || 'S')::interval)
FROM step_seconds
```

Conversion to function is easy, let me know if have trouble with it.
One problem with this solution is that `extract epoch` always assumes 30-days months. If this is problem for your use case (long intervals), you can tweak the logic for getting seconds from interval.

Comment: wait extract epoch has every month at 30 days?

Answer (score 1):

You can divide the difference between the end and the start value by the number of values you want:

```
SELECT * 
FROM generate_series('2017-01-01'::timestamp, 
                     '2017-01-04'::timestamp, 
                     ('2017-01-04'::timestamp - '2017-01-01'::timestamp) / 7)
```

This could be wrapped into a function if you want to avoid repeating the start and end value.

Comment: I've found that with this method it occassionally returns 8 rows instead of 7 like with (2017-'1-05 and 2017-01-01) I've fixed it by adding an hour to the interval